# Layout Glitch on Android 4.4 (below)

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been working in an App and got a strange glitch in it's layout:

[image]

It's happening in all the views and I loose some hours trying to figure it out, but without success.
You guys know why this is happening ?

clientes_criar_fragment.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="381dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_spTipoDocumento"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientes_labelNome"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="616dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/endereco_labelEndereco"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientes_spTipoDocumento"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/clientes_textDocumento"
        android:hint="@string/Documento"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
    android:layout_width="616dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_enderecos"
    style="@style/card_external"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientes_labelInscricaoEstadual"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
    android:layout_width="624dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_contatos"
    style="@style/card_external"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/clientes_enderecos"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientes_labelLimiteCredito"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="1248dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_labelNome"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/clientes_textNome"
        android:hint="@string/Nome"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="616dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_labelInscricaoEstadual"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endereco_labelEndereco"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/clientes_textInscricaoEstadual"
        android:hint="@string/Inscricao_Estadual"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="624dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clientes_labelLimiteCredito"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/clientes_labelInscricaoEstadual"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endereco_labelEndereco"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/clientes_textLimiteCredito"
        android:hint="@string/limite_de_credito"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

CriarClienteFragment.java

```
    public class CriarClienteFragment extends Fragment {
    private ClientesBusiness _clienteBusiness;

    private ListagemEnderecoCard _listagemEnderecoCard;
    private ListagemContatoCard _listagemContatoCard;

    private Spinner _spTipoDocumento;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewCriar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clientes_criar_fragment, null);
        this._clienteBusiness = new ClientesBusiness(inflater.getContext(), 0);
        this.SetView(viewCriar);

        return viewCriar;
    }

    private void SetView(View view)
    {
        //Iniciando o dropdown
        this._spTipoDocumento = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.clientes_spTipoDocumento);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(view.getContext(),
                R.array.tipo_documento_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        this._spTipoDocumento.setAdapter(adaptador);

        // Iniciando a visualização da listagem de endereços
        this._listagemEnderecoCard = new ListagemEnderecoCard(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), this._clienteBusiness);
        this._listagemEnderecoCard.init();
        CardViewNative cardViewEndereco = (CardViewNative) view.findViewById(R.id.clientes_enderecos);
        cardViewEndereco.setCard(_listagemEnderecoCard);

        // Iniciando a visualização da listagem de contatos
        this._listagemContatoCard = new ListagemContatoCard(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), this._clienteBusiness);
        this._listagemContatoCard.init();
        CardViewNative cardViewContato = (CardViewNative) view.findViewById(R.id.clientes_contatos);
        cardViewContato.setCard(_listagemContatoCard);
    }
}
```

Not all views are fragment, this is one of my views who have this problem and the a strange glitch in the buttons happen as well, they all have this weird shadow. It appear to not happen in lollipop above.
If it is missing anything just ask and I edit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to find something similar here, I look on that.

Comment: Yeah, that's not an easy thing to search for. I know it had been asked before that one, but when it started getting repeated, and I looked for the first post, that was the only one I could find.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you're awesome. It seems as something on the instant run with the latest version of graddle. Returned to 2.1.0 and everything is fine now.